# finish caller activity when starting another one

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button, activity-finish

[image]
like in the diagram I want to close all previous activities when starting another one. I tried a lot with flags, but it doesn't seems to work. eg. when starting Activity B on Activity A I called

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent = intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent = intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent = intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent = intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

But the `finish()` Method isn't called in Activity A.
I've got a global class, called `Navigation` which extends `Activity` to handle things like this in one class. All orange Activities extends my Navigation, the blue ones don't. BackButton behaviour seems to work fine, but the `finish()` method isn't called when starting another activity. Do I have to explicitly call `finish()`? Where? If I do it in `onStop` I can't go back to Activity X when restarting the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
startActivity(intent);
```

simply put

```
finish();
```

in activity that you want to finish.
Flags are needed only when ie. you   want to clear activity stack

Comment: is my stack clear when calling finish() every time I start another activity?

Comment: finish() only finishes that activity in which it is called. When you got ie. 3 items on activity stack than when you call finish() you got 2 items. No other items are removed. If you want clear all items use:
`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Comment: then I have to use this flag AND call finsih? do you know a way to show the current stack?

Comment: oh, and if I want to go back via backbutton I must not call finish? (when calling Register/ForgotPassword from Login)?

Comment: finish() -> finish only THIS activity which is called in.
flags -> clear all activity stack(even caller activity). No matter where it is called.
back button -> in standard implemetation - finishes current activity.
So:

Login -> Register (back Login on stack) -> Login (no Register on stack)
Login -> Register (finish Login on stack) -> Login (no Register on stack)

Login -> Register (intent with flags) -> Other Activity (with clear stack)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right just add finish() in your code like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent = intent = intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```